# Conditional calculation python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

A dataframe is given, and a calculation shall be done as stated below:

*DF as-is*

[image]

*DF to-be*

[image]

Column Epsilon shall be calculated:

- Where beta = same values, the two rows belong together. (10 -> 1,1 or 20 -> 2,2)
- Column epsilon of such a pair is the sum of the 2 values (12+5=17; 13+6=19)
- Print the result (17, 19) in the row of the pair (1,1 or 2,2) where delta = yes
- Set epsilon of the row to NULL where delta = no
  row 50 is unchanged, since it does not belong to any pair.

I hope i was clear :) if not, please ask me. Tnx for any input!

Comment: Can you please edit your question post the dataframe as text? (so we can copy and paste it)

Comment: BTW: this is not a homework. i am in the process of learning python for my company. above example is a simplified version of a problem i want to solve. the boolean mask as stated below worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask. Sort values by `delta` column then keep the track of duplicated `beta` values.

```
m = df.assign(delta=df['delta'].eq('x')).sort_values('delta').duplicated('beta')
epsilon = df.groupby(['beta'])['epsilon'].transform(sum)

df.loc[~m, 'epsilon'] = epsilon
df.loc[m, 'epsilon'] = 0
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   alpha  beta gamma delta  epsilon
0     10     1     x             17
1     20     1           x        0
2     30     2     x             19
3     40     2           x        0
4     50     3                   18
```

Input dataframe:

```
data = {'alpha': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        'beta': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'gamma': ['x', '', 'x', '', ''],
        'delta': ['', 'x', '', 'x', ''],
        'epsilon': [12, 5, 13, 6, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
   alpha  beta gamma delta  epsilon
0     10     1     x             12
1     20     1           x        5
2     30     2     x             13
3     40     2           x        6
4     50     3                   18
```